# How to duplicate the full screen on a second monitor, but hide a specific window?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I want to duplicate my screen on a projector attached to my laptop (which I know how to do).

I've also a small text-editor window (with my notes) that I'd like to be always-on-top on my laptop, but hide completely on the second display.

One solution I got proposed was to set up the screens in extended-mode. And then capture the window I *do* want to project using VLC or OBS, and preview it on the second screen. However, I will be switching between multiple apps (such as browsers, slides, code-editors...), all of which I want to project. So I am looking for a way to specify the window I *don't* want to project.

Comment: A projector is the the same as a second monitor. Operate it accordingly.

Comment: I know that; but how does that help my case?

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question you had that understanding. Basically what you can or can't do with a 2 monitors setup is the same if the second is a projector. So, extended desktop is obviously your starting point (mirroring shows the same in both). Then yes, you can have different software running in different parts of the extended desktop.